# Ajuda com Requisições Ajax e FORM

Tags: php, html, ajax, pdo

Estou usando o formulário abaixo para fazer a consulta por produtos...

```
<form action="prod_index_consulta.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="busca" method="post">
    <span>Busca Avançada</span>
    <a class="search" id="<?php echo $res['titulo'];?>" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="img/search.gif" /></a>
    <input style="width:100%;" size="23" type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
</form>
```

E usando esse código abaixo na pagina "prod_index_consulta.php" para retornar o resultado da consulta...

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$buscar = $_GET['buscar'];  
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho, menu, produto WHERE titulo LIKE '%$buscar%'");
$sql->execute();
foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){

echo'
    <div id="prod" style="background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';width:33%; float:left; padding:10px 0;" class="center_prod_box">
        <div align="center" id="titulo" style="width:100%;">
            '.$res["titulo"].'
        </div>
        <div align="center" style="width:100%; height:130px; background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';">
            <div align="center">
                <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                    <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/'.$res["img01"].'" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="preco" style="width:100%;">
            <span style="">R$ '.$res["preco"].'</span>
        </div>                        
        <div align="center" id="carrinho" style="width:100%;">
            <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                <img style="width:100%; max-width:20px;" src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
            </a>
        </div>                        
     </div>
';
}?>
```

E tentei usar o SCRIPT da Requisição da seguinte forma, porém sem sucesso...

```
<script language="javascript">
////// Link para visualizar o produto quando consultado pelo titulo /////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({url:"prod_index_consulta.php?buscar="+cod,success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar para que eu possa trazer o resultado da consulta para dentro da DIV '#visual', ficarei muitissimo agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos fazer algumas alterações no `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"prod_index_consulta.php?buscar="+cod,
    dataType:'Json',
    success:function(data){
        $('#visual').html('');
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            $('#visual').append(value);
        });
    }
});
```

E no `PHP`:

```
<?php
    include "conexao.php";
    $buscar = $_GET['buscar']; 
    $sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho, menu, produto WHERE titulo LIKE '%$buscar%'");
    $sql->execute();
    foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){
        $return[]='
        <div id="prod">
            <div align="center" id="titulo" style="width:100%;">
                '.$res['titulo'].'
            </div>
            <div align="center" style="width:100%; height:130px; background-color:'.$res['fundosite_cor'].';">
                <div align="center">
                    <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='.$res['codigo'].'">
                        <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/'.$res['img01'].'" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div align="center" id="preco" style="width:100%;">
                <span style="">R$ '.$res['preco'].'</span>
            </div>
            <div align="center" id="carrinho" style="width:100%;">
                <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo='.$res['codigo'].'">
                    <img style="width:100%; max-width:20px;" src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>'; 
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Olá Smith...
Fiz a alteração que você recomendou e consegui fazer com que o retorno seja na DIV '#visual', porém agora ele está me enviando este erro...`Notice: Undefined index: buscar in C:\wamp\www\Commerce\prod_index_consulta.php on line 4`.
Ou seja nesta linha `$buscar = $_POST['buscar'];`.

Comment: é porque não é `POST` e sim `GET`, já mudei na resposta

Comment: Valeu Smith, mas agora ele me retorna sempre o ultimo produto cadastrado, independente da palavra que for consultada... Alterei o atributo `input class="search"` para `a class="search"`...Editei minhas perguntas com as alterações, para que você possa ver se estou fazendo certo, OK?

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações ai na resposta, verifica se ta rodando

Comment: Da uma olhada no Ajax, pois ele não está fechando...